# Django 1.95 template i18n not working

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I am trying to translate the string from English to zh-hans

In the `settings.py`

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-hans'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I have run the `python manage.py makemessages -l zh-hans` and  `python manage.py makemessages -a` for many times.

The .po file is simple as following:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2016-09-07 09:53+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: blog/views.py:18
msgid "author"
msgstr "作者"
```

In the html file:

```
        <div id = "info">
            <p>
                {% trans "author" %} : {{ blog.author }}
            </p>
        </div>
```

The tag returns "author" instead of Chinese characters.
Also I have tried ugettext in `view.py`

```
def detail(request, slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    msg = _("author")
    print(msg)
    context = {
        'blog': blog,
        'author': msg,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

The msg is still "author".

Using

```
 {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
 {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}
```

The language code is zh-hans.

So what's going wrong here? How to show the translated string in the template? Thank you

Comment: Did you compile your .po files with `python manage.py compilemessages`?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Yes, I have done many times

Comment: And you sure your django finds your translations? Last time I had problem it was due to my translation not bieng discovered https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations so I had to manually add them in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOCALE_PATHS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very silly mistake.

Although in the `setting.py` the Chinese language code can be set as 'zh-hans', to implement the i18n, it should be makemessages -l zh_hans instead of zh-hans.